# How to create Mount script or Link2sd symbolic link in adoptable storage (format microsdcard as internal memory) any help

Tags: app2sd, adoptable-storage, link2sd

**Question : How to create Mount script or Link2sd symbolic link in adoptable storage (format microsdcard as internal memory) any help**

I have an old mobile with upgrade of Android 6.0.1 marshemellow with 16gb internal memory(11gb reserved for system and only 5 GB free space for user apps and files). I want to make 128gb  or 64 GB microsdcard as internal memory.

I had changed many apps manifest through apkeditor and changed their default install location. To external still some files are moved and many apps cAnt change the manifest.

So to add at least 60gb I decided to move apps and folder redirect dcim  download whatsapp Facebook to external micro SD card so that at least 2gb space is always free in internal memory.

Now the question and problem is that can I cheat or mislead the Android 6.0.1 marshmallow (without root or with root) through

1. using  apps like  link2sd or app2sd or folder redirection appps or
2. through SM PM command

> adb shell sm list-disks adoptable sm partition disk:179:160 mixed 25
> adb shell sm format private:179,3

3. through creating own symbolic link boot.init script to decieve Android 6.0.1 is  and move or link apk files like data lib hex off apk to.memory card
4. Can both adoptable storage (format as sd as internal and the link2sd symbolic link mount scripts) work together as after formatting as card as internal Android  assumes no external card and the how will be it work from redirecting or symbolic link to internal folder. I tried Inc it gave "Mount script error"

Any way or script if I can write or tell it will be great help for my problem.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/130014/2021/9/26

Comment: @alecxs bro gr8 love  to see if reply after long long time...Yes I remember that was my android 5.1.1 phone which is not working and damaged ...This post is for another phone that is Android 6..0.1 ....Which I formatted again

Comment: @alecxs bro in this query as it's with Android 6.0.1 marshmallow I am able to  Micrrsdcard  formatted as internal.memory and can move 10℅ to 20% to external micro SD card  by default it installs automatically ...others I edited apkeditor apps manifest default install location to external thus it's successful to.move (25%-35%) rest 55%- 65% apps are still unmovable now what I am planning is to link or symbolic link or mount or move those 65% apps by cheating receiving Android 6.0 .1 and linking  or folder redirect mount script to Micrsd card format as internal as link2sd aapp do ..

Comment: @alecxs bro my major concern and study from.forum.linka are that as in Android 6.0.1 marshmallow the microsd card formatted as internal so it mounts that card to name /sdcard whereas if I root and use linked it will search and work on external as card not a mounted folder to creTe symbolic links within external card....Now how to create our own mount script which can redirect  symbolic the internal memory apps to the /scarf mounted folder that Microsdcard formated as internal...Is it possible or just my imagination....Can u help me in guiding or writing such mount script

Comment: grep /mnt/expand /proc/mounts

Comment: @alecxs bro here is a link in XDA where a developer in  1st page gave solution to change linked boot script for Android 6.0.1 https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/link2sd.3222034/

Comment: Thx, I have replied in that thread...

Comment: @alecxs thanks bro will try